# How to fix "assertion failed" in Unreal Engine 4.11

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

After Building the Fresh source and Running the Fresh Install of UE_4.11.0 it loads 100% and the new project is created 100% but while loading the project to 99% it crashes with the error.

> LOG: Assertion failed: !bSrcDepthWrite || bDstDepthWrite
> [D:\UE4.11.0\Engine\Source\Runtime\Windows\D3D11RHI\Private\D3D11Commands.cpp [Line:715]

Source Code of D3D11Commands.cpp

```
void FD3D11DynamicRHI::ValidateExclusiveDepthStencilAccess(FExclusiveDepthStencil RequestedAccess) const
{
    const bool bSrcDepthWrite = RequestedAccess.IsDepthWrite();
    const bool bSrcStencilWrite = RequestedAccess.IsStencilWrite();

    if (bSrcDepthWrite || bSrcStencilWrite)
    {
        // New Rule: You have to call SetRenderTarget[s]() before
        ensure(CurrentDepthTexture);

        const bool bDstDepthWrite = CurrentDSVAccessType.IsDepthWrite();
        const bool bDstStencilWrite = CurrentDSVAccessType.IsStencilWrite();

        // requested access is not possible, fix SetRenderTarget EExclusiveDepthStencil or request a different one
        check(!bSrcDepthWrite || bDstDepthWrite);  // Line: 715  
        check(!bSrcStencilWrite || bDstStencilWrite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: UE 4.25.3 out there, why are you still using the older one? Als similar issue in [answers.unrealengine.com: Assertion failed: !bSrcDepthWrite || bDstDepthWrite UE 4.11](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/343115/view.html)

Comment: @JeJo I am using in Laptop Corei3 and it will never support UE 4.25.3.

Comment: @JeJo I am trying from the latest version if not supported then I downgrade. The v4.11 gives me a green signal :P

Comment: @Arnold-Baba *it crashes with the error* -- I know it may sound nitpicky, but assertions are *not* crashes.  An assertion is generated by the program because of a violation that the program knows about.  That is different from a crash, where the program just stops dead for no apparent reason.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I build it from the source downloaded from the torrent, you mean the code is modified?

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is a difference between a crash and an assertion.  An assertion is generated by the program because some condition was violated, and the program explicitly is checking for this condition.  If the condition is not met, then the program halts.  That is different from a crash, where the program just plain old stops running, due to whatever reason (not known by the program or by the programmer, until the program is debugged).  Obviously the issue is `check(!bSrcDepthWrite || bDstDepthWrite);`, where the program is checking this condition, and it isn't met.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Now I have build another version from the source UE_10.0 and it is working fine and even loaded very fast.

Comment: @Arnold-Baba -- When you get an assertion, check what the values are at the line you stated the assertion occurred.  You didn't state what those values were, even in the original question.  This important piece of information was missing from your post.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In the error Log I have a popup on screen with only one line that I have posted in the main post question and the line number in the file is also commented with the number 715 in the source code.

Comment: It looks like you are not debugging your code.  Your program halted on an assertion.  That assertion has variables right there for you to report to us what the values are.  You failed to do so.  That is the information you missed giving us.  If you told us what the actual values were, then that gives more information on the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Now I will Debug it with X64dbg and will update the question if I found anything useful but it will be in assembly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I checked it on my friend's PC and it's working fine. The issue is with Direct X features in my laptop, My processor didn't support Direct X 11 Feature 10.0

Answer (score 0):

Need delete all from directorey C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\UnrealEngine\EngineVersion